# How to extract data from table PostgreSQL in Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I need extract selected data from table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79B36.png). It means I want to import all author's articles, save it, show author's name. I have to count number of top words in all articles every author.

It's part of my code:

```
prev = ''
stri = ''
for row in data:
        print (row[1])
        if row[1]!= prev: 
            crear_tabla( ''.join( map(str.lower, row[2].split())))
            all_article_str = "".join(row[1])
            stri+=all_article_str
            split_it = stri.split() 
            print(split_it)
            Counte = Counter(split_it) 
            most_occur = Counte.most_common(10)
            print(most_occur)
            print(row[2])
        for i in range(10):
            insert_into(''.join(map(str.lower,row[2].split())), str(most_occur[i]))
        else: continue
        prev = row[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out psycopg2, it's the most popular python package for working with Postgres https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/

Here's how it works if you want to read a dataset into Python (don't forget to install the package first using pip).

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='your_db' user='your_name' host='localhost' password='your_password'")
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM your_table")
results=cur.fetchall()
```

The object 'results' can then be interated over to return the dataset on row at a time. You could then work this into your existing code to manipulate the data.